# Modify the path

Tags: vba, excel, path

I have this code, that open all the files. The path is written in the cell (1,1). Eventually in the end of the path I have to put \, so I want to know if there is something that I could do for put \ automatically in the end of the path.

```
Sub openfiles()
   Dim directory As String, fileName As String, sheet As Worksheet, i As  Integer, j As Integer, finalRow As Integer
   Application.ScreenUpdating = False
   directory = Cells(1, 1)
   fileName = Dir(directory & "*.xl??")
   Do While fileName <> ""
      Workbooks.Open (directory & fileName)
      fileName = Dir()

   Loop
   Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Are you asking how to modify `Cells(1,1)` to add a "\" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a "\" to the end of the string

```
directory = Cells(1,1).Value & "\"
```

Comment: @user45 You might want to check the last character of `Cells(1,1).Value` to make sure it doesn't already have a trailing slash before appending one.